# Using return value of function on multiple places in template

Tags: javascript, angularjs

If I have a function that returns an object. eg.

```
$scope.getPoint = function()
{
    //some calculation logic goes here
    return {x:1,y:2};
}
```

And I want to display properties from it in a template:

```
<b>som html</b> x: {{getPoint().x}} y:{{getPoint().y}}
```

That would result in two calls to the function.
(I know, angular may call it a gazillion times anyway)

Is there any way to reuse the same return value in a template?

Comment: As long as http ajax requests are not involved, why do you care? +1 anyway.

Comment: Maybe run the function & set it's result to a variable in your model before binding to the page? PS- I don't use angular so may be off base

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
<b>som html</b> <span ng-repeat="(key, value) in getPoint()">{{key}}: {{value}}</span>
```

should work, at least according to the [docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angRepeat).

**EDIT**: In fact it does: [Plunk](http://embed.plnkr.co/lrQxto/preview)

Answer (score 0):

As long as the value isn't going to change, why not make it a self-calling function?

```
$scope.myVar = (function () {
    return { x: 1, y: 2 };
}());
```

Comment: It says: "some calculation logic goes here"

Comment: I guess the question becomes, are the variables that the calculations depend upon going to change? Currently, the code isn't watching any other variables. The question is just to have a value cached so that the function is run a single time even though it might be rendered in multiple spots in the template.